# How to implement Expand/Collapse for a table with Multiple columns - GWT - Google Visualization API

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I have list of Items with parent child relation.
At present I am displaying them in a single table. In each row, fist column starts with number of '-'s indicating the depth.

Now I want show only top level items first and with a '+' button before that.
When the user clicks on the '+' button it should turn to '-' and the children of that particular Item need to be displayed.

So, Please help me how to implement that Expand and Collapse functionality in GWT.

**EDIT:**

I have my Items in a tree format.
Now I am creating a DataTable and Displaying it using GoogleTableChart
The code as follows:

```
            DataTable data = DataTable.create();
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Item Name ");
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Item Id");
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Quantity");
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Price ($)");
            data.addRows(treeList.size());
            int i=0;
            while(i<treeList.preOrderTraversal().size())
            {
                int col=0;
                Item d=(Item) treeList.preOrderTraversal().get(i);
                int level=d.getLevel();
                //setting values to DataTable goes here
                i++;
            } 
            GoogleTableChart tblChart = new GoogleTableChart();
            vPanel.add(tblChart.showFlexibleTable1(data));
```

Comment: Most tags are unrelated. Question doesnt have code. Post code or will be closed. Read the gwt documentation.

Comment: Added my code. please help me

Comment: That code is unrelated as it shows a plain table not a tree. Read the gwt docs.

Comment: present the code display a plain table only. The "treeList" contais all the items with the details of the parents and childs. now i want to display them in a expand/collapse model

Comment: like I said, the google visualization is unrelated. post code with an actual tree view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

I create Nested VertialPanels for each Item. And put the reference in a map.

Hide/unhide the panels based on clicks.

For root Item take one panel and add all its children.
After adding one child, add all its children to another panel,hide it and add to root panel.
repeat the steps recursively.

before each row place put (+/-) label and add click handler which take item id as parameter.
when these lables are clicked, based on the status we hide/unhide the panels, taken from the map.

Any Better Solution ... ??